# How to creat login session and save login state

Tags: jquery, asp.net, session, authentication

I have a login function below:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static bool isAccountAvailable(string userName, string passWord)
    {
        BDTestDataContext bdc = new BDTestDataContext();
        if ((from q in bdc.Accounts where q.User == userName && q.Password == passWord select q).Count() > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

And jQuery

```
   $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: 'Home.aspx/isAccountAvailable',
                data: JSON.stringify({ userName: $('#txtUserLogin').val(), passWord: $('#txtPassLogin').val() }),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.d == true) {
                        alert("Login success");                         
                    }
                    else
                        alert("Error!");
                }
            });
```

I want to creat session to save login state when i open another page. ex:/manager.aspx

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
   [WebMethod(Description="isAccountAvailable",EnableSession=true)]
    public static bool isAccountAvailable(string userName, string passWord)
    {
        bool flag = false;
        BDTestDataContext bdc = new BDTestDataContext();
        if ((from q in bdc.Accounts where q.User == userName && q.Password == passWord select q).Count() > 0)
            {
               flag  = true;
            }
             //No need to check else condition bcz flag is already False
            Session["isAccountAvailable"] = flag ;

        return flag
    }
```

Edit  as op requirement:

```
 [WebMethod(Description="isAccountAvailable",EnableSession=true)]
    public static string isAccountAvailable(string userName, string passWord)
    {
        bool flag = "";
        string Uname="";
        BDTestDataContext bdc = new BDTestDataContext();
        if ((from q in bdc.Accounts where q.User == userName && q.Password == passWord select q).Count() > 0)
            {
               flag  = true;
               Uname  = userName;
            }
             //No need to check else condition bcz flag is already False
            Session["isAccountAvailable"] = flag ;

        return string ;
    }
```

and in your success function:

```
         success: function (data) {
                if (data.d !="") {
                    alert(data.Uname);                         
                }
                else
                    alert("User Name is Empty");
            }
```

Comment: I want get UserName, How do? Bro, help me, plz!

Comment: Where you want to get username in webmethod or in js ?